# Power BI Extracting Text from a column

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I am fairly new to Power BI and I need to extract the following text from a column field/column in Power BI

```
1st 7 Weeks
2nd 7 Weeks
1st 8 Weeks
2nd 8 Weeks
```

and for those titles that don't have any weeks indicated, I need to set the extracted value to Full 16 Weeks (which doesn't exist in title field and I need to give that value)

I try to use split function but the value that I am extracting is not consistently appearing in the same order and for some title the placement is different. I would appreciate any guidance and help.

I have attached an image of the title field.

I tried split column but due to titles not being written in a consistent format I was unable to use split and I tried Advanced editor but not able to get the query work.

Title formats:

```
NUR-4450-Z2-Holistic Nursing Care of Women and Families-Fall 2022-Clinical 06 - 1st 8 Weeks - Tuesday - Motl

NUR-3480-Z1-Holistic Nursing Care Adults and Families I-Fall 2022-Clinical 02 - Wednesday - Prov Park - Schaw

NUR-4410-Z1-Holistic Nursing Care of Children and Families-Fall 2022-Clinical 08 - 2nd 8 Weeks - Tuesday - Ratl

NURS-4200-AN1 Nursing Adults Acute Health - Fa23-NURS-4200-AN1  

NURS-3510-AN1 Ns Adlt/Chr Hlth - Su23-NURS-3510-AN1
```

[image]

Comment: Don't paste pictures of text. You will need to provide sample data as copiable text and expected results.

Comment: @DavideBacci thank you for taking a look at the question. due to privacy I can't share the data, I provided different types of formats that are in my topic column. would that work, if now, how else can I get help for this solution. Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Yes that's fine but format them as tables so we can see the columns. You also need to add what your expected result looks like. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post

Comment: Using regular expression (see: https://regex101.com/r/9D8Nze/1 ), and [Using regular expressions in power bi desktop](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Community-Blog/Using-regular-expressions-in-power-bi-desktop/ba-p/1744760), this might be possible... (I did not test that!)